# printing backslashes in file paths

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a file with a name starting with "n" (like "nFileName.doc"). Why is it that when I get its path as a string and print it to the console the "\n" sequence is not treated as an escape sequence (and broader - single backslashes in the path are not treated as escape characters)?

```
string fileName = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents").Where(path => Path.GetFileName(path).StartsWith("n")).First();

string str = "Hello\nworld";

Console.WriteLine(fileName); // C:\Users\Wojtek\Document\nFileName.doc
Console.WriteLine(str);      //Hello
                             //world
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14583874/335858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of escaping is only relevant for *source* code (and other specific situations such as regular expressions). It's *not* relevant when printing a string to the screen - `Console.WriteLine` doesn't have any such concept as escape sequences.

For example, consider:

```
string x = @"\n";
```

This is a string with two characters - a backslash and `n`. So when you print it to the screen, you *get* a backslash and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `fileName` will equal

```
C:\\Users\\Wojtek\\Document\\nFileName.doc
```

in your code so the `n` at the starting of your file name will not be treated as part of any escaped character.

Answer (score 0):

Because the *backslash* that comes before the `n` is already escaped in your file path. Consider this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\\n");
```

This will write `\n` to the console because the `backslash` is escaped...

In order to verify this debug your program and look at the value of `fileName`, you will see that all backslashes are escaped.