# How to replace with Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have special case where I need to replace string

```
(src="cid:image001.png@01D081C1.C5908B40")
```

with the following

```
(src="\\resources\\images\\image001.png")
```

with in the given text.

It should replace in all occurrences where ever it appears in given text.

I tried like this but its not working as expected.

```
fileName ="image001.png"; 

Regex.Replace(body, "[src=\"cid:" + fileName + "@](*)[\"]", "src=\"\\Resources\\Email\\" + emailID + "\\" + fileName + "\"");
```

Comment: @Biffen I need it in C#.

Comment: Side note: please consider using MSDN to get initial samples of how to use functions. I.e. [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows code that works and it could help understanding why your version did not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things to remember:

- When using variables to initialize regex patterns, use `Regex.Escape` (e.g. you have a dot in `image001.png`, so it must be escaped as `image001\.png` in the pattern)
- When using variables in replacement strings, it is a good idea to add `.Replace("$","$$")` to replace literal `$`s (e.g. `emailID.Replace("$", "$$")`).
- It is a good idea to use [verbatim string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583874/verbatim-string-literals-v-escape-sequences) when writing regex patterns, so as not to use double-escaping (that facilitates rgex writing and testing in online and other regex testing tools).

I cannot guess what your `emailID` variable looks like, thus, I would not use a variable in the replacement string to obtain the output you want.

So, the code I suggest:

```
var fileName = "image001.png";
var body = "(src=\"cid:image001.png@01D081C1.C5908B40\")";
var pattern = @"(\(src="")cid:(" + Regex.Escape(fileName) + @")@.*""\)"; // will look like (\(src=")cid:(image001\.png)@.*"\)
var restt = Regex.Replace(body, pattern, @"$1\\resources\\images\\$2"")");
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
fileName =
  Regex.Replace(body,
                "[src=\"cid:" + fileName + "@](*)[\"]",
                "src=\"\\Resources\\Email\\" + emailID + "\\" + fileName + "\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
    string input = "(src=\"cid:image001.png@01D081C1.C5908B40\")";
    string replacement = "src=\"\\\\resources\\\\images\\\\$1\"";
    Regex rgx = new Regex("src=\"cid:(image[0-9]+\\.png)@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+\"");
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(input, replacement));
```

Output: `(src="\\resources\\images\\image001.png")`

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/a33Dh1)